# Latex editor with custom build option

Tags: pdf, latex

i am supposed to write my master's thesis in latex. I was given a template from my thesis supervisor. It has own building script. I would like to use some window editor (like: Texmaker or Gummi), but non supports external building tool (for pdf preview mode) or i didn't find how to use it. 
What i expect:

1. Option that allows me to target location of build tool
2. Option that allows me to target location of created pdf

Do you know any app that would fulfil my requirements?
THx